# Passing class pointer to a function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, arguments, wt

I want to use different WText instances in another function, but as I want to have just one control function, I'd like to pass them in there.

The code with current setup compiles but fails due to some memory fault which I don't understand.

```
class mode : public WApplication
{
//..
private:
//..
void someFunc();
void control(WText* texty);
WText* text;
WText* text2;
WText* text3;
//...etc
};

void mode::someFunc(){
     control(text); //how to pass it?
     //might pass  text2 or text3 as well
}

void mode::control(WText* texty){
     texty->setText("blabla");
     //..
}
```

Comment: this code wont fail with some memory fault! Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: *When* and *where* do the program fail? How does it fail (crash or unexpected results)? Have you used a debugger to help you find the problem? How about a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: why are `text` and the others pointers? Just never use raw owning pointers as members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text member is a pointer to the object WText,
The first thing you need to do is a create a new WText object:

```
void mode::someFunc() {
    text = new WText();
    control(text);
}
```

please remember about destroy text object after use.

Comment: Thanks, actually I had called text = new WText(); after control(text) without noticing it. :(

Comment: Or perhaps set the things you need in the constructor?